# On Orientation change cannot update the fragment view in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, screen-orientation

I have a MainActivity.java which has 2 fragments:

1) Fragment1.java -> Has a RecyclerView of items.

2) Fragment2.java -> Displays the details of the item when it is clicked.

In Portrait orientation only Fragment1.java or if item clicked then Fragment2.java is visible.
In Landscape mode both the fragments are visible side by side.

This works fine in both Portrait and Landscape orientations if I start the app in that orientation. 
However if I change the orientation in between when the app is still running, then I get the error IllegalStateException : Cannot perform this action after onSaveInstanceState whenever another list item is clicked.  The action on which it throws the error is transaction.commit().

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest seeing if you have set the Orientation mode in the activity tag in the manifest  and if you did remove it.Android handles this automatically.
such as :

```
<activity
android:name=".MyActivity"
android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

Regarding the different looks of the fragments when the app is in Landscape or Portrait , this has to do with the Layout you choose in the xml file.
Relative , Linear etc. Please checkout the Android official documentation  and use that meets your needs.